# From a list of matrices, create an array containing the i-th and j-th element of each matrix

Tags: python, list, matrix

I have a list of matirces each containing pixel values of a screen at a given moment. Matrix1 contains pixel values at moment1, matrix2 contains pixel values at moment2 and so on. Lets say I want to take a look at how one individual pixel evolves throughout time.
I created some dummy matrices to test how that would work and put them in `mylist`:

```
m1=[[1,2],[3,4]]
m2=[[1,2],[3,4]]
m3=[[5,6],[7,8]]

mylist=[m1,m2,m3]

print(mylist)
```

Then I wanted to select the `(0,0)` element of the second matrix:

```
print(mylist[1][1][0])
```

This gives me the expected output `1`.
Then I wanted to generalize it and pick the `(0,0)` element of every matrix, which should give me the output `mynewlist=[1,1,5]`:

```
mynewlist=[]

for i in 2:
    mynewlist.append(mylist[i][1][0])
    
print("hello hello")
print(mynewlist)
```

However, it gives me the error message:

```
for i in 2:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

What did I do wrong?
How can I bypass this problem?
Is there any other (most propably smoother and better) way to select the `(i,j)` element from each matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better aproach would be to directly loop through the ellement of mylist as:

```
   mynewlist = [] 
   for image in mylist:
       mynewlist.append(image[1][0])
```

This makes your code more readible. And now it doesn't matter how many images you have in your initial list.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(len(mylist)):
    mynewlist.append(mylist[i][0][0])
```

Answer (score 1):

You have made a simple error, you missed the range function to make it act as an iterable

```
for i in range(2):
    mynewlist.append(mylist[i][1][0])
```

without it `i` cant actually go over values since all it sees is a `2`
Though a more elegant solution has been suggested by @Bart van Woesik which ensures that you don't need to actually count the number of values and set a range